# Any advice on how to clean up/shorten my code?

Tags: php

Is there anyway I can shorten this code and make it more efficient.
I haven't messed about in PHP in awhile and am a bit rusty.

So far - I've pulled an array from a external JS file from Google FreeBusy API & then pulled an array from a WordPress database to compare the two.

If the {start-times} inside the array don't match up with each other, then delete the item from the DB.

I've had to make two new arrays so that each of them have the same details and I don't compare the google array with irrelevant items that I get when I pull the array from the DB.

I'm not sure having multiple foreach loops is the right way to do it, if any PHP experts can give me some tips on how to make it much efficient it would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

$apiArray = json_decode($myArray, true); //decode the json into a php array

$notCal = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_amelia_appointments` WHERE
`internalNotes` = 'freeBusy' AND `serviceId` = 4", ARRAY_A); 

foreach ($notCal as $row) { 
    $databaseArray[] = $row['bookingStart'];
}

foreach ($apiArray as $rows) { 
  $formattedItem = $rows['start'];
  $formattedItem = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "$formattedItem - 10 hours")); 
  $googleArray[] =  $formattedItem;
}

$result = array_diff($databaseArray, $googleArray); 

foreach ($result as $itemtoremove) { 
  $sql = $wpdb->delete('wp_amelia_appointments', array ('bookingStart' => $itemtoremove)); 
}
```

Comment: This may not be what you're thinking of in terms of "clean up/shorten" (your algorithm seems reasonable on quick glance), but the comments feel excessively verbose (e.g. `//for every difference in the array do this`) and make the lines run very long. Can you avoid the horizontal scrollbar appearing on this code block? Perhaps putting this in a function with params would help clean it up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate some of these `foreach` loops if you are pulling a single key from each nested array `there's a function for that`,

instead of:

```
foreach ($notCal as $row) { //adding only the start times from the database 
// to an array called databaseArray
    $databaseArray[] = $row['bookingStart'];
}
```

DO

```
$databaseArray = array_column($notCal, 'bookingStart');
```

> **array_column** — Return the values from a single column in the input array
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

You can even do this if you wish

```
$result = array_diff(array_column($notCal, 'bookingStart'), $googleArray);
```

And If I had the data from $apiArray,  I could probably replace that `$googleArray` with `array_walk` or `array_map` but alas I am to lazy to think that hard right now.

**Ok I lied:**

```
$result = array_diff(array_column($notCal, 'bookingStart'), array_map(function(&$item){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$item} - 10 hours"));
}, array_column($apiArray, 'start')));
```

Now you can remove all this

```
foreach ($notCal as $row) { //adding only the start times from the database 
    // to an array called databaseArray
    $databaseArray[] = $row['bookingStart'];
}

foreach ($apiArray as $rows) { //adding only the start times from google 
      // into an array
      $formattedItem = $rows['start'];
      $formattedItem = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "$formattedItem - 10 hours")); 
     //gotta convert times from google so that it mathces the time format used in the db
      $googleArray[] =  $formattedItem;
}

$result = array_diff($databaseArray, $googleArray);
```

Keep in mind I'm working off a limited knowledge (and ability to test) of what this data looks like.

Example (how I tested it):

```
$apiArray = [
    ['start' => date('Y-m-d')]
];

foreach($apiArray as $rows){
     $googleArray[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$rows['start']} - 10 hours"));
}

print_r( $googleArray );

//now this doesn't look much smaller then the above, but because it returns
//exactly what we want (given the code I've seen), you can get rid of
//$s and just stuff it in array_diff.

$s = array_map(function($item){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$item} - 10 hours"));
}, array_column($apiArray, 'start'));

print_r( $s );
```

Output:

```
//foreach
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-08-21 14:00:00
)
//array map
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-08-21 14:00:00
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e904c5f4fc421cf2f17608d498693e4ec39d6c9d)

**So in Summery**

```
<?php

$apiArray = json_decode($myArray, true); //decode the json into a php array

$notCal = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_amelia_appointments` WHERE
`internalNotes` = 'freeBusy' AND `serviceId` = 4", ARRAY_A); 

$result = array_diff(array_column($notCal, 'bookingStart'), array_map(function($item){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$item} - 10 hours"));
}, array_column($apiArray, 'start')));

foreach ($result as $itemtoremove) { 
  //for every difference in the array do this
  $sql = $wpdb->delete('wp_amelia_appointments', array ('bookingStart' => $itemtoremove)); 
  //delete each row that matches the booking start time
}
```

**A few more things you can do:**

You can probably do the delete on the entire array `$result` not sure how it's done in wordpress of the top of my head. But something like `DELETE FROM wp_amelia_appointments WHERE bookingStart IN( ... )`.  This should be fairly clean data because part of it was ran though `date()` and the other part comes from what I assume is a `date` or `datetime` DB field `bookingStart`.  This somewhat limits your attack surface.  Now I am not saying to not properly prepare your query, I'm just saying that the data is limited in it's attack vectors (for SQLInjection), but this would eliminate the last `foreach` loop.

Last change is (I don't use Wordpress that much as you can tell) you may/should be able to change your first query to:

```
"SELECT `bookingStart` FROM `wp_amelia_appointments` WHERE
`internalNotes` = 'freeBusy' AND `serviceId` = 4"
```

Switching `*` for `bookingStart` and then fetch just the column.  I could tell you how to do it in PDO, not wordpress (off the top of my head).  But that would save you the `array_column($notCal, 'bookingStart')` call on that result set, by selecting only what you need in the format that you need.

Hope it helps.

The last thing I will say, is short code is not always readable code. You should fully understand what I did above to reduce this.  And be able to process that code in your mind (that's what I do mostly).  PHP don't really care if your code is a bit longer, and the performance gains here are probably not worth mentioning (besides the DB stuff) which I didn't, but you should try to do.

These are my priorities when I write code:

- code that works (and is bug free)
- code I can read
- code that performs well
- code that is concise and short

So this is really the bottom of the list, but these things are not mutually exclusive.  You can do all of them at the same time.

Cheers.

Comment: Best answer I have ever received on a stack-overflow question!  Cheers for explaining it! Really helps me improve - wasn't expecting an answer this in-depth at all. I kept writing comments but then I would see it's been updated again! I hadn't even thought of using array_column or array_map to merge it all together but it makes sense the more I think of it. I really appreciate this, thanks again!

Comment: Sure, sorry about the updates, lol, it's a process even for me.  And I been doing this for years and years (like 6 maybe 7 now).  So I see one thing and think what about this.  We won't mention that I am Dyslexic and can't spell for ... well I leave it at that.

Comment: The last thing is, the closer you can pull your data to what you need it to be, the less post DB processing and thus the less code it takes.  I only work with wordpress for themes, nothing back end.

Comment: Hahah, I'm still very new in the whole dev world so I really appreciate any feedback and tips on how to improve! Cheers again mate!

Comment: I'd suggest checking out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  I thought for sure it would get flagged before I finished my answer.

Comment: Didn't even know that existed, thanks. Yeah I've had a few questions flagged before in the past - thought I'd give it a shot anyway and see if it anyone replies.

Comment: Sure, I have an account on there and about 1/2 dozen other boards :) .... lol .... hey I get bored at work sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions:

It might be possible to simplify getting `$databaseArray`. Rather than `SELECT * FROM`, you could do `SELECT booking_start FROM` and then use `$wpdb->get_col` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column).

Purely stylistic, but you can simplify the second loop a little:

```
foreach ($apiArray as $rows) { 
    $googleArray[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$rows['start']} - 10 hours"));
}
```

Finally, if you want to reduce the number of DB interactions, you could replace the final loop with a single delete with a `WHERE booking_start IN` clause.